# Can somebody explain this manuscript to me?

Tags: notation, sheet-music, time-signatures

[image: march piece]

Is it a pickup, an alteration of some sort? The time signature in the proper part (manuscript) is 2/4. This part is a trio in a march and it looks like the time signature is modified without showing but I can't figure out how or what. Anybody got any ideas?

Below is what I'm getting with the 2/4 time signature.

[image: what I am getting]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My guess is that this is what you're looking for:

[image]

The first three notes that are smaller are called [grace notes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grace_note). They are usually played slightly before the beat.

This is my guess because the two quarters with the two quarter rests take up the whole measure (if it is 2/4)

Answer (score -1):

Looks like a three-note acciaccatura to me (I just hacked your bitmap to make it clear).

[image]

Apart from the three note acciaccatura, there are four eighth notes in the bar, which is correct for 2/4 time signature.

If the music were typeset, the acciaccatura would have smaller noteheads.